# Why this code is not showing the background image?

Tags: javascript, html, css

My HTML code-

```
 <html> 
 <head> 
 <style type="text/css"> 
 { 
 /*for setting background image*/
 background-image: url('C:/Users/SONY/Desktop/CSS/images.jpg'); 
 background-attachment: fixed 
 } 
 </style> 
 </head> 
 </html>
```

This code is for setting the background image. But it's not showing the 
result. I've not created two files. Like one for CSS and another HTML file.
I've compiled both the files into one.

Why am I not able to see the background image? Despite giving the 
correct path for the URL.

Comment: Is the page hosted on a server, or is it on your machine? Note also missing selector.

Comment: replace `{` with `html {`

Comment: There's no class, id or element assigned to the CSS.

Comment: did you try with the below answers ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying background image to none of the class/id or any html tags like html, body etc. either you need to add a class or id or need to apply style to the inbuilt tags. you can try this

```
  <html> 
   <head> 
   <style type="text/css"> 
   html{ 
   /*for setting background image*/
   background-image: url('C:/Users/SONY/Desktop/CSS/images.jpg'); 
   background-attachment: fixed;
   } 
   </style> 
   </head> 
   </html>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the element for which want to give particular CSS properties like `html`, `body`, `.class`, `#id`.

```
body {
   /*for setting background image*/
   background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/1/'); 
   background-attachment: fixed 
}
```

Here is the link of working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hs9426hm/).

Comment: There's no link and no code either, please review your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think your code under css folder, so the line should be :
background-image: url('images.jpg');

Comment: i've tried this but it's still not showing the background image.

Comment: body { 
   /*for setting background image*/
   background-image: url('C:/Users/SONY/Desktop/CSS/images.jpg'); 
   background-attachment: fixed; height:800px; width:1200px; 
   }  can try with these codes.

Comment: Thanks too. but you did not approve this answer? can you?

Answer (score 0):

```
Use this style in your code. If want to pick image from local computer.

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        html {
            background-image: url(./images.jpg);
            background-attachment: fixed;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>

</body>

</html>
```